# Getting exception -java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error: drawImage is not allowed within a text block

Tags: java, exception, pdfbox

Getting error while using DrawImage() method to add image to exiting PDF file on each page (PDFBox api) to achieve it but getting below exception

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error: drawImage is not allowed within a text block.
>
> Method:
> contents.drawImage(ximage,80,80);

I am not sure about existing PDF file it may contain data or image on each page. I would like to add small image on each page. It is fine it overlap exiting data.

```
org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.image.PDImageXObject  ximage = null;
org.apache.pdfbox.rendering.PDFRenderer pdfRenderer = 
  new org.apache.pdfbox.rendering.PDFRenderer(doc1);

for(int c=0; c<=doc1.getNumberOfPages()-1;c++){
  java.awt.image.BufferedImage bim =
  pdfRenderer.renderImageWithDPI(c, 300, 
  org.apache.pdfbox.rendering.ImageType.RGB);
  ximage = org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.image.LosslessFactory.createFromImage(doc1, bim);
 }
for (i = 0; i <= pageCount - 1; i++) {

// get all pages
PDPage = pd1.getDocumentCatalog().getPages().get(i);

org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPageContentStream contents = new org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPageContentStream(pd1, PDPage, org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPageContentStream.AppendMode.APPEND, true);

//Begin the Content stream 
contents.beginText();

contents.setFont(font, fontSize);


contents.setLeading(14.5 f);

contents.newLine();

contents.drawImage(ximage, 80, 80);
// contents.drawInlineImage(ximage,400,400);
contents.endText();

contents.close();
}
```

Want image to be present on each page of PDF. Please suggest the best way to to place an image on the PDF page.

Answer (score 1):

The exception text "drawImage is not allowed within a text block" tells it: "beginText()" and "endText()" make a text block. So move "contents.endText();" before "drawImage". (Btw you are not showing any text?!)

Bonus hint: add a fifth "true" parameter to the "PDPageContentStream" constructor. This will prevent weird effects with some PDFs (see the javadoc).